# aws api gateway lambda authorizer cognito-idp client get_user error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am creating a lambda authoriser.

In which I want to check that the user exists in my cognito user pool and then check some other things that I cannot do with the normal cognito authorizer.

The following code snippet produces the error:

> NotAuthorizedException: An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException)
> when calling the GetUser operation: Invalid Access Token

```
cognito_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)

  
    response = cognito_client.get_user(
            AccessToken=event["authorizationToken"] 
        )
```

I'm testing it by passing the `id_token` I get when I login to cognito just like I do to test the normal cognito autozizer.

What is wrong is not `id_token` the token that I have to pass to the lambda autozizer ?

Isn't `event["authorizationToken"]` the token I should pass to get_user ?

How can I get from event the token that I have to pass to get_user ?

Answer (score 0):

Login user should add following scope "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin" during log-in to use this method. If u have access token you may decode token and get same user details values from that token.